# IP - Inferred .NET type mapping elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have read this document [inferred .net type mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html) and noticed that there is a "ip_range" but there is not "ip". I created a model class that is currently of datatype String. Is there a specific IP datatype in C# I can use? Or should I leave it as String for the datatype?

[image]

In C# I have, `public String Ip { get; set; }`

Comment: String is fine most of the time but there is an in-built `IPAddress` type in the `System.Net` namespace. No idea if you can use this with elasticsearch implicitly though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no type that implicitly or infer maps to the `ip` data type. The options are

1. explicitly map using [fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html) and the `.Ip(...)` method
2. explicitly map using [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html) and the `IpAttribute`
3. explicitly map using [the visitor pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html)
4. [dynamically map using dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html), perhaps by matching type and name pattern

Comment: This is good to know, thank you for the list of options!